# How to call Delphi function (upper layer) from C (lower layer), which is built in libXXX.so?

Tags: c, delphi, firemonkey

I have a FMX project running on Android.
I can make the FMX project execute a C function in “libTest.so” as follows:

**main.pas**:

```
TMyCallbackFun = procedure(Param: Integer) of object;

procedure TForm1.MyCallbackFun(Param: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('MyCallbackFun called');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Handle1: THandle;
  fun1: function(MyCallbackFun: TMyCallbackFun): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Handle1 := LoadLibrary(PChar('/system/lib/libTestC.so'));
  if Handle1 <> 0 then begin
    fun1 := GetProcAddress(Handle1, PChar('RegisterCallback'));
    if Assigned(fun1) then begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('RegisterCallback returns ' + IntToStr(fun1(MyCallbackFun)));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**TestC.c**:

```
int (*RegisteredCallback)(int);
struct itimerval t;

void alarm_handler(int a) {
    LOGD("alarm_handler called");

    t.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    t.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    t.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    t.it_value.tv_sec = 0;

    RegisteredCallback(8);
}

int RegisterCallback(void *CallbackFun)
{
    LOGD("RegisterCallback called");

    RegisteredCallback = CallbackFun;

    t.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    t.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
    t.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    t.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &t, NULL);
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    return 5;
}
```

I want the C function “RegisterCallback” in “libTest.so” to keep the Delphi function pointer of “MyCallbackFun”, then at certain time (such as a timer expiration) the “libTest.so” can call the function pointer with parameter.

But it crashes when the timer expires:

```
10-28 19:17:55.161: D/TestC(673): RegisterCallback called
10-28 19:17:58.161: D/TestC(673): alarm_handler called
10-28 19:18:00.001: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(980): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
10-28 19:18:00.001: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(980): handleTimeUpdate
10-28 19:18:00.101: D/dalvikvm(31379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 382K, 75% free 2759K/10856K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 32ms
10-28 19:18:00.161: D/TestC(673): alarm_handler called
10-28 19:18:00.291: I/ActivityManager(980): Process com.embarcadero.ExternalLibrary (pid 673) has died.
10-28 19:18:00.291: I/WindowState(980): WIN DEATH: Window{41b7b560 u0 com.embarcadero.ExternalLibrary/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
10-28 19:18:00.291: W/ActivityManager(980): Force removing ActivityRecord{41a03fe0 u0 com.embarcadero.ExternalLibrary/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}: app died, no saved state
10-28 19:18:00.311: D/Launcher(1348): Broadcasting Home Idle Screen Intent ...
10-28 19:18:00.321: D/CAT(1249): StkAppService: 7called on slot:0
10-28 19:18:00.321: D/CAT(1249): StkAppService$ServiceHandler: Need to send IDLE SCREEN Available event to SIM
10-28 19:18:00.321: D/CAT(1249): StkAppService$ServiceHandler: Event :5
10-28 19:18:00.321: D/CAT(1249): StkAppService$ServiceHandler: SetupEventList is not received. Ignoring the event: 5
10-28 19:18:00.351: D/Zygote(378): Process 673 terminated by signal (11)
10-28 19:18:00.371: W/InputMethodManagerService(980): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 673 uid 10122
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Could any expert tell me how to fix the code to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the signature of `MyCallbackFun`?

Comment: BTW, I post complete sourcecode FYR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TMyCallbackFun = procedure(Param: Integer) of object;
```

The `of object` Delphi function is a method pointer. It is a double pointer type. So, `SizeOf(TMyCallbackFun)=SizeOf(Pointer)*2`. One pointer is the instance, the other is the code. When the method is called there is an extra, hidden, parameter which is the instance, `Self` from inside the implementation. You cannot use method pointers here. You need it to be

```
TMyCallbackFun = procedure(Param: Integer); cdecl;
```

Or, as is likely, if you need to pass an instance then do it like this:

```
TMyCallbackFun = procedure(Param: Integer; Data: Pointer); cdecl;
```

On the C side that is

```
void (*RegisteredCallback)(int, void*);
```

Note that I changed the return value from `int` to `void` to match the Delphi. And also that I've used `cdecl` since I assume that is the default calling convention for your C compiler.

You also need to store the data as well as the callback:

```
void (*RegisteredCallback)(int, void*);
void *RegisteredCallbackData;
....
int RegisterCallback(void *CallbackFun, void *CallbackData)
{
    ....
    RegisteredCallback = CallbackFun;
    RegisteredCallbackData = CallbackData;
    ....
}
```

To invoke the callback from the C code you do:

```
RegisteredCallback(..., RegisteredCallbackData);
```

On the Delphi side you implement the callback like this:

```
procedure MyCallbackFun(Param: Integer; Data: Pointer); cdecl;
begin
  TForm1(Data).MyCallbackFun(Param);
end;
```

And you need to declare `fun1` to match:

```
fun1: function(CallbackFun: TMyCallbackFun; CallbackData: Pointer): Integer; cdecl;
```

I think that's everything!